# Hide zones in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I am looking for a way to hide certain zones on 1 particular page in Orchard CMS, I am using version 1.6.1.

Some background to my issue - every page on the site has a header and footer as defined in the `Layout.cshtml` file. For 1 page on the site I want to hide the header and footer which is made up of 6 zones. In MVC I would add another layout file and use nested layouts but I know this can't be done in Orchard.

I have a solution that does the job, however I am not keen on it as it involves putting code in the `Layout.cshtml` file, my solution is as follows

```
if (Request.Url.PathAndQuery.Contains("register-1"))
{
    Model.Header1 = null;
    Model.Header2 = null;
    Model.Header3 = null;
    Model.Header4 = null;
    Model.Footer1 = null;
    Model.Footer2 = null;
}
```

This is coupled with doing a null check before outputting the zone like so

```
@if (Model.Header1 != null)
{
    <div id="layout-banner">
        @Zone(Model.Header1)
    </div>
}
```

Is there a way to do this without having to put code in the `Layout.cshtml` file? Or perhaps there is a better approach all together?

Comment: What is populating these zones? Widgets? Create new layers?

Comment: It is widgets yes. That's a good point, I could edit the layer rule that populates these zones to not include the URL for this page. If you want to post this as an answer I'll mark as accepted if it does the trick.

Comment: I can confirm this works, if you want to post an answer I will accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a layer to hide the widgets, that uses a `not url("~/register-1")` to exclude the page. The widgets that are placed in this layer will not appear on your register-1 page.

Answer (score 1):

You can create layout alternate for pages. If it is only one page that url alternate will be suitable.

1. Copy your Layout.cshtml (from current theme folder)
2. Rename one to Layout-url-your-page-url.cshtml
3. Also you should activate Url Alternates Module

For more defails view http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Alternates

Comment: Or use a layer to hide the widgets.

Comment: This will work however it will leave me with lots of duplication across the 2 layout files, something I'd like to avoid.

@BertrandLeRoy As I mentioned in a comment on my question, I'm going to edit the layers that output the widgets on this page to exclude the URL. If you'd like to post this as an answer I'll mark is as accepted if it does the trick.

Comment: I can confirm this works, if you want to post an answer I will accept